# Spring Security Access Denied Handler gives HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

On updating Spring version from 4.2.2 to 4.3.5, I am facing a problem while logging in from login.jsp page.
When I delete all cookies and then try to login it gives HTTP 403 Access Denied due to missing CSRF token that should be handled by the accessDeniedHandler but the when the accessDeniedHandler forwards the request to "forbidden.jsp" page, it gives an error of "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported".
Here is the code of configuration for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    logoutSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/login?logout");
    logoutSuccessHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");

    // @formatter:off
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/forbidden")
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(appRememberMeServices)
            .key(appRememberMeServices.getKey());
    // @formatter:on

    authorizeRequests(http);

    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
}
```

With spring version 4.2.2 it works fine with no code changes.

When I add a controller and allow "POST" request on "/forbidden", it works fine but when I add a view controller mapping it expects a "GET" request but gets a "POST" request.
So if anyone knows what is the change in spring version 4.3.5 from 4.2.2 that it is making a "POST" request rather than a "GET" request to access denied page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084111/http-status-405-request-method-post-not-supported-spring-mvc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269383/http-status-405-request-method-post-not-supported-in-spring-mvc?rq=1

Comment: @rohanagarwal - Nope these do not help, the problem is different.

Comment: @Anubhav Verma: did you solved the problem?

Comment: @Ralph not yet.